# Asterisk: Change the IP of PBX, and the phones do not register anymore

Tags: asterisk

Because of IP conflict with a new hardware that was installed (long story), I had to modify the IP of my Asterisk Now based on Asterisk 13.12.1 and FreePBX 13.0.192.16.
The IP was 192.168.1.100 and became 192.168.1.200.
Obviously, also change the IP of “SIP server” on all phones, to match the new IP address. I clarify that all the phones are within the local network, there are no remote phones.
The result is that no phone is registered.
I assume that was a problem with the firewall, but even disebled it completely, it does not work either.
Can you give me any idea what I might be going through?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Iit may be posible that sip is bound to 192.168.1.100, run "sip show settings" in the asterisk CLI (asuming you are using chan_sip) and check the Bindaddress setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only for close topic, the problem was that the firmware of the Grandstream phones that I configure do not accept that in the field Account Name have alphabetic and numerical characters. The line number must be included in this field. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are no any way give guess what you dooing wrong based on info you have provided.

Can suggest run wireshark or tcpdump near phone and check what happens with your sip packets.